# is it necessary to clean session before using them?

Tags: php, security

i always do a cleaning method for sessions before i use them an example would be

```
mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']);
```

the session only conains the id to the physical file that is stored on the server. how can this session be used client side to do malicious activity? is it then necesarry to clean the session before using it?

Comment: what i meant is is it necessary to sanitize a session no matter it a integer or string. since the session through the client side only sees the id value inside the session of the actual physical file of the session which contains the true data. is it necessary to sanitize a session? if its not sanitize how can it be used maliciously? like i said the session doesnt contain the true session data to the client side user. just the id of the actual file stored on the server.

Answer (score 1):

If you read **user input** from the session, then you have to sanitize it. If the user cannot influence the value (maybe a timestamp), there is no need to check it.

Sanitizing is necessary before you are using the value, e.g. before you output to an html page or before you use the variable in an SQL statement. To write to an HTML form you can use the function `htmlspecialchars()`, to use the variable for MySql SQL statements use the spezialized function `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Comment: Sanitizing when writing to the session is pretty much always wrong - you should only do it when using the data in a context where it's necessary (plain sql queries).

Comment: @ThiefMaster - I clarified the post, maybe it was written a bit misleading.

Comment: you should also sanitize users input into sessions as it may for example contains some serialized objects that may cause problem when session would be restore. This was exploited on cakePhp in the past. Users inputs must be sanitize when at input time not only at rendering time.

Comment: @malko: Are you serious? If the framework has a problem with storing *any* data in its session it's clearly a problem of the framework that needs to be fixed. Saniziting for SQL/HTML output (which is completely different and using both "breaks" one of the output formats) should be done when that output type is needed, not when storing it... However, if you want to completely disallow HTML it's fine to do so before storing it. But if you just want to block HTML by escaping it - do it during rendering (you could want to render it as plaintext where no escaping would be necessary/allowed)

Comment: @malko - Didn't know about that, could you provide a link? When sanitizing user input before writing to a session we modify the content (cannot get the original input back), how would you sanitize it?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use the mysql_real_escape_string function when you are querying a MySQL database.

When you say ID of the file, do you mean the the variable always contains an integer? If this is so then there is no reason to escape it as it is not a string.

If you do not know for sure what the session variable is going to contain, then you should always escape/sanitize it.

Comment: Correction: sanitize data that is being used _in any query_, not just INSERTs/UPDATEs.

Comment: how can a session be used maliciously if not santized? it doesnt contain any data to the public user.